# Android 8 or above App Crashing On Android Oreo With Firebase Performance SDK

Tags: android, firebase, android-8.0-oreo, firebase-performance

I have added latest Firebase Performance SDK and in Android 8(Oreo) or above app is crashing with error message OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added.

**App Level build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
```

**app Module Level build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

    other
   ..............
   ..............

    // Android support
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    // Android Gms Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

**Log**

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added
        at android.view.View.removeFrameMetricsListener(View.java:6862)
        at android.view.Window.removeOnFrameMetricsAvailableListener(Window.java:890)
        at android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl.remove(FrameMetricsAggregator.java:436)
        at android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator.remove(FrameMetricsAggregator.java:246)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zza.onActivityStopped(Unknown Source:64)
        at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStopped(Application.java:258)
        at android.app.Activity.onStop(Activity.java:1950)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:636)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop(AppCompatActivity.java:184)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1382)
        at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7526)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4591)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4652) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1784) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7002) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: By the log, it's saying you are trying to remove `OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener`  . Are you adding this listener ?

Comment: I haven't even registered this listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to downgrading the version of `perf` from 16 to 15. Might be this issue will fix in upcoming new version.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.+'
```

Or you can remove `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` line from `AndroidMainfest.xml`

Comment: Removed android:hardwareAccelerated="true" line from AndroidMainfest.xml, everything working great.

Comment: in my code `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` so i downgraded, still let me check